# Access JSON array values?

Tags: php, json, parsing, multidimensional-array, data-access

eSo I've got some parsed php data whiched I've fetched from my database and then parsed to JSON with json_encode(). Then I've used JSONparse() to make objects of my array. My code looks like this:

`$.get("fetchDatabase.php", function(data){

      var parsedData = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
}`

I'm left with the array  `parsedData`  which looks like this:

```
[

{"person0":{"name":["Erik Steen"],"age":["1"]}},
{"person1":{"name":["Frida Larsson"],"age":["1"]}},
{"person2":{"name":["Abdi Sabrie"],"age":["2"]}},
{"person3":{"name":["Achraf Malak"],"age":["3"]}},
{"person4":{"name":["Adam Anclair"],"age":["1"]}}

]
```

I've placed those arrays in an array named

```
var peopleArray= { people: [ parsedData ] };
```

So far so good. Now what I want is being able to access certain persons attribute. Like names or age. How do I target those attributes? I've tried to print those attributes with no luck. I tried:

```
alert (peopleArray.people[0].person1.name);
```

Whiched returns:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
```

**How can I access those attributes?**

Comment: Looks like you have a typo 'namn' ?

Comment: FYI, `peopleArray` is not an array, it's an object.

Comment: the type was when I converted my variabel name to something more understandable. I've edited that out now. 

bfvaretto: is that a big problem for me? How can I access names for peoples? Or if that's not possible: how can I make it an array instead of an object? Skip parseJSON?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apart from the typo ("`namn`") the problem is you're putting an array inside an array:

```
var peopleArray = { people: [ parsedData ] };
```

Since `parsedData` is an array then what you end up with is a structure like this:

```
// peopleArray
{ people :  [ [  { "person0" : ... }, ...  ] ]  }
//  oops -----^
```

See the problem? Since `parsedData` is a already an array the correct code would be:

```
var peopleArray = { people: parsedData };
```

Comment: I see. I've tried using your suggestion: 

var peopleArray = { people: parsedData };

But it makes no differences - I'm still not able to access my names by using: peopleArray.people[0].person1.name

Is still undefined

Comment: What's the value of `peopleArray.people`? What's the value of `peopleArray.people[0]`? What about `peopleArray.people[0].person1`?

Comment: `peopleArray.people[0]` gives me `[object Object]`.

Comment: What does the object look like? (Use `console.log()` with Firebug or Web Inspector, not `alert()`.)

Comment: Thx, that advice was very good. I didn't know that you could log-out the objects. With that knowledge I would have been able to solve this issue as it was just a matter of using e.g ['name'] instead of [0]